# does this create a closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I know this is the classic closure manner:

```
var dvs = document.getElementByTagName("div");

for (var i = 0, len = dvs.length; i < len; i++) {
    dvs.onclick = (function(i_) {
        return function() {
            alert(i_);
        };
    })(i);
}
```

However, in my application I am often confused, and my application is based on Google maps.

```
var app = function() {}
app.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        this.map = ..;
        this.infowindow = ..;
    },
    initEvent: function() {
        var that = this;
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
            that.infowindow.open(...);
        });
    }
}
```

Inner the `initEvent` method, I create a variable named `that` to refer to the context `this`, then call it in the callback function.

Does this create a closure?

I think so, because when the function`addListener` returns, the variable `that` is still referred, is closed.

Is this true?

Comment: Btw, instead of that `that` variable, you can use `.bind(this)` to set the context of the inner function manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically spoken, *every* function in ECMAscript creates a closure when called. Its just the way *lexical scope* works. Without going into grand detail, the *anonymous function* which serves as event handler for the *click event*, closes over its *parent contexts*. One of those is the *anonymous function* which gets assigned to *initEvent*.

So, yes, the inner function creates a closure and therefore has access to `that` during its lifecycle.

```
Global Context <> initEvent <> click-event-handler
```

That is how the *scope chain* pretty much would look like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You use `Technically spoken` here. Then I wonder if closure created by the inner function is the samething as it in the classic closure example? if not,what is the difference?

Comment: @hguser: I just said that, because the *Global Context* is always present. That in turn means, that regardless where you call a function it'll *always* close over that *GC*. In Practice its more common to use the term *closure* when another *function context* is involved.

Comment: @hguser: What he means is that in javascript, global variables are technically closures too.

Comment: @slebetman—closures are generally considered to exist only if they persist beyond the life of the outer function, such as when an immediately invoked function expression returns a function. And since the global object is at the end of every scope chain, its properties (i.e. global variables) are always available to such functions. Some also think closures only exist if such variables are actually accessed, although technically I don't think that's necessary and they might be optimised away by the compiler.

Comment: @jAndy—instead of `closes over its parent contexts` you can also say "has its scope chain preserved", and so has access to the variables in outer contexts even after those functions have finished executing. Maybe that helps, maybe not…

Comment: "every function in ECMAscript **has the potential to create** a closure when called" - would be a better statement. The potential is realised only if a persistent external reference to an inner function exists after the outer function has completed and returned. In practice, it's actually academic at which point you choose to regard a javascript closure to have been created. Scope chain behaviour, which is a precursor to closure, will exist from the moment an external reference to the inner function is created. True closure only occurs on suppression of garbage collection.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: I'd agree that it might depend on definition here.  Still, if we look at it on implementation level, every function that is getting called will copy a reference to its parent *Activation Objects* / *Lexical Environment Records* and store it in its own *Execution Context* as *[[ Scope ]]*. One could say that at this point we already closured data, but as you correctly stated, there might be other definitions.

Comment: I think the reason why a closure is generally considered not to have formed before an outer function has returned, is that until that point nothing has actually closed! The existence of a scope chain is just "business as usual" for Lambda-capable languages.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: I wouldn't call the *global object* nothing, but I still get your point.

Comment: Good point :), 'nothing' is incorrect. How about "... until that point something we just opened has not yet closed" or more formally "... until that point at least one execution context in the current thread is still open", or ..... it's hard to know where to stop. I'm sure we're singing from the same hymn-sheet here but accurately describing it is another matter.